# ExtJS: JsonStore is not loading at all

Tags: json, extjs, store

i've a jsonstore:

```
jstore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields: ['id', 'timer', 'name', 'message'],
    root: 'data',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                    url: 'chat.php',
                    method: 'GET',
            }),
            remoteSort: false
});
```

which is not loading data from the url.
My php file works properly, if i type in my url the same url used by the store, the output is this:

```
{fields: ['id', 'name', 'time', 'message'], 'data': [{id: '5', name: 'stefano', time: '2012-05-21 14:08:58', message: 'mymessage'}]}
```

which should be a correct json string, isn't it?

The store is not loading neither with the autoload nor with a explicit call to

```
jstore.load({params: {mode:'RetrieveNew', id:'-1'}});
```

Any idea on what may cause this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with store loading.

In order to fix it I have replaced Ext.data.JsonStore with Ext.data.Store. Other parameters are the same. 
So here is my example of autoloaded ExtJS store:

```
this.datesStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                        id: 'datestore',
                        root: 'dates',
                        autoLoad: true,
                        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                                    url: '/url/to/the/data',
                                    method: 'GET'
                                }),
                        fields: ['date']
                    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You did a typo: `autoLoad` not `autoload`

Comment: Yup, thanks..fixed, sadly that seemed to have no impact on the problem, firebug console still silent, there isn't any sign of communication between the client and the server side.

Comment: Don't you have to specifically configure model you're using?

Comment: Isn't it done by specifying the fields and the root in the store? I'm sorry, i'm kinda new to this feature of extjs..

Comment: +1, correct. The problem is related to adding `autoLoad` and set it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

just to add my solution:

```
var stateStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    root: 'states',
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'js/query/states.json',
        method: 'GET'
    }),
    fields: ['stateCode', 'stateName'],
});

stateStore.load();
```

And my **states.json**:

```
{
  "states": [
      { "stateCode": "01", "stateName": "Johor" },
      { "stateCode": "02", "stateName": "Kedah" },
      { "stateCode": "10", "stateName": "Selangor" }
  ]      
}
```

Hope it will help the rest ;)